# Get the index of a datagrid component on rollover in AS3

Tags: datagrid, mousehover, actionscript-3

I've run into some problem trying to get the index of a row currently being hovered opon on a datagrid component of flash using ActionScript 3.0.

So please how can I get the row index of a datagrid on mouse rollover in AS3.

Thanks

Comment: Oh well...kinda stumbled upon the answer while RTMIHM (Reading The Manual In Hyper Mode)

    new DataGrid().addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, function(e:ListEvent) {
    trace(e.rowIndex);
   });

and thats all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER` event rather than a basic mouse over

```
import fl.events.ListEvent;

var sampleItem1:Object = { Name:"John Alpha",   Number:"555-123-0101", Email:"jalpha@fictitious.com" };
var sampleItem2:Object = { Name:"Mary Bravo",   Number:"555-372-3322", Email:"mbravo@fictitious.com" };
var sampleItem3:Object = { Name:"Trevor Gamma", Number:"555-485-1212", Email:"tgamma@fictitious.com" };
var sampleItem4:Object = { Name:"Susan Delta",  Number:"555-987-3434", Email:"sdelta@fictitious.com" };     

dg.columns = ["Name","Number","Email"];
dg.addItem(sampleItem1);
dg.addItem(sampleItem2);
dg.addItem(sampleItem3);
dg.addItem(sampleItem4);

function gridRollOver(e:ListEvent):void
{
    trace("rowIndex: " + e.rowIndex + " columnIndex: " + e.columnIndex);    
}
dg.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, gridRollOver);
```